# why a .png file suddenly have black background in tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, png

i wrote this code on the school computer, and it was totally fine. i wrote the same code on my personal pc and now it shows the picture with no transparency (with black background). the picture is the same picture(a png with no background)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1300x731")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
photo = Image.open("logo.png")
zoom = 0.5
pixels_x, pixels_y = tuple([int(zoom * x)  for x in photo.size])
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo.resize((pixels_x, pixels_y)))
panel = Label(root, image = img).place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.1, anchor = 'center')
#panel.grid(row=5000, column=3)
#panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")


root.config(cursor="@curs.cur")
while True:
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can use a generator expression to get a tuple instead of list comprehension, also only `Canvas` support transparency. also don't use `*` when importing

Comment: Why do you put `root.mainloop()` in a infinite while loop?  BTW you should see gray background (default background color of a label) if the PNG has transparency.

Comment: PNG file not means all with transparency, it depends the alpha layer. Maybe your logo.png is not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

try it with another import method.

use photo = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")

this should remove the black background.

- Remove the "while True:"

root.mainloop() is a loop by itself